# Как вывести определённое количество пользователей

Tags: python

Есть код наподобие этого:

```
members = [Ваня, Петя, Ира]

print(
f'Список участников клана:'
f'1.{members[0]}'
f'2.{members[1]}'
f'3.{members[2]}'
)
```

Допустим список участников должен идти до 50 игроков.
Я не понимаю как можно это реализовать, мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь нажимал "Список участников" выводился весь список, но допустим если в клане 20 игроков из 50 возможных, то если я продолжу выводить по индексу, поймаю ошибку, что элемента под индексом 21 не существует.

Как сделать чтобы список выводился до последнего элемента по шаблону, а именно:

1.Ваня 2.Петя и тд.

Понимаю, что нужно использовать цикл for, но не понимаю как именно.
Важно чтобы это было одним сообщением.

Если кому надо: для Бота Vk, библиотека Vkbottle.

Answer (score 0):

```
members = ['Ваня', 'Петя', 'Ира']

print('Список участников клана: ', end='')
print(*[f'{i}.{name}' for i, name in enumerate(members, 1)])
```

Вывод:

```
Список участников клана: 1.Ваня 2.Петя 3.Ира
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант можно составлять строку заранее, а потом уже отправлять ее человеку

```
members = ['Ваня', 'Петя', 'Ира']

result = ''
for index, member in enumerate(members, start=1):
    result += f'{index}. {member}\n'
    
print(f'Список участников клана:\n{result}')
```